# Baking Tezos with Kiln: deviating BC source path

Tags: kiln, blockchain

I have a question to the use of Kiln software with deviating blockchain source path.
I bought a new SSD and installed it as an additional hard drive -> copied Tezos blockchain there
In  /var/lib a new symbol link was created to the new directory. Rights are the same as /var/lib/kiln/
Run: "failed", "permission denied". 
All rights are exactly the same as in old directory. 
What can be the reason?
My guesses are: 
- it is linked to the inode 
- Kiln cannot work with symbol links.
Any help or hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't figure this out: You can actually change the directory that kiln uses for the tezos node data. It's a bit odd that the symlinks break things, but you ought to be able to not need a symlink.

[Blockchain file directory change in Kiln](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1746/blockchain-file-directory-change-in-kiln)