# Blockchain file directory change in Kiln

Tags: kiln

I want to setup full node of Tezos, as far as I understand I can do it with help of Kiln. That is why I want to ask is it possible to change a directory where Kiln downloads blockchain data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kiln has a parameter called kiln-data-dir which you can use to point the  other directory where you'd like the tezos-client and tezos-node directory instead of the default /var/lib/kiln.

On ubuntu, set this via /etc/kiln/args:

KILNARGS="--kiln-data-dir /tmp/kilntezos/"